# Url parameter extraction in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-web-api

I have a server-side endpoint service, that delivers endpoints to a javascript service.

An endpoint could look as follows: `http://localhost/{value}/223/{type}`

I would like the javascript service to parse the endpoint's values (in curly braces) to the current url.

Thus:

```
function extractParameters(endpoint, currentUrl) {
//do some magic here

}

var data = extractParameters('http://localhost/{value}/223/{type}','http://localhost/test/223/hat');
```

returns an object like this `{ value = 'test', type = 'hat'}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far

Comment: I dont have a take, so far - i was thinking of using regex matches to find all matches not having curly braces, that try to find the indexes in the string for the matches to extract the values i want... But it seems rather extensive, i think? 

Any suggestions? I don't nessecarily need an implementation - more the process of getting there :) @allicarn

Answer (score 0):

I utilized the `split` function to parse out the `http://` from both URLs, and then split up both urls into arrays of folders/parameters/etc. so that they looked like: `["localhost","{value}","223","{type}"]` and `["localhost","test","223","hat"]`.

I then iterated through the first (pattern) array to pick out the things you wanted to collect, using regex to see if it had curly braces as the first and last character.  If it did, I pulled out the value between the curly braces using `substring` and cached it as the key.

Then, since both arrays should follow the same pattern, I used the index of that key to get the value from the url that was passed.

I'm not sure how flexible it should be, but there are a couple scenarios that this code does not cover very well: if the URLs are of different lengths, if the value of `localhost` or `223` matters in your pattern - should it fail if those do not match?

```js
function extractParameters(pattern, currentUrl) {
  // extract out the http://
  var patternArr = pattern.split('//');
  if (patternArr.length > 1) {
    patternArr = patternArr[1];
  }
  var currUrlArr = currentUrl.split('//');
  if (currUrlArr.length > 1) {
    currUrlArr = currUrlArr[1];
  }

  // Separate each folder/parameter
  patternArr = patternArr.split('/');
  currUrlArr = currUrlArr.split('/');

  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < patternArr.length; i++) {
    if (patternArr[i].match(/^\{.*\}$/)) { // It matches the pattern {likethis}
      var key = patternArr[i].substring(1, patternArr[i].length - 1);
      var value = currUrlArr.length > i ? currUrlArr[i] : ""; // Get the value at the same index
      obj[key] = value;
    }
  }

  return obj;
}

var data = extractParameters('http://localhost/{value}/223/{type}', 'http://localhost/test/223/hat');
console.log(data);
```